# Find Item in Array / Replace With Array Using Awk?

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I'm trying to make my code more clean. My function seems rather oblique to do a simple find/replace.  Is there a cleaner way to do this find/replace array function with awk or something similar?

```
# Finds first item in array that matches find item, and replaces it with 1 or more array elements.
# Preserves sort order of original array.
find_replace_in_list(){
    # $1 = list
    # $2 = find item string
    # $3 = replace array.

    local -n _list=$1
    local -n _replace_list=$3
     
    for i in "${!_list[@]}"; do # Iterate over indices.

        if [ ${_list[$i]} == "$2" ]; then
            # Insert the replace array starting at indice.
            local p=$((i+1)) # Get indice just after match.
            local array_pre=${_list[@]:0:i}
            local array_post=${_list[@]:p}
            local new_array=("${array_pre[@]}" "${_replace_list[@]}" "${array_post[@]}")
        echo "${new_array[@]}"

        return # Break out of loop. Only replace first match.
        fi
    done
    # Nothing found.  Return orginal array.
    echo "${_list[@]}"
}

: ' Example use ^^^ 
list=('a' 'b' 'c' 'd')
find='b'
replace_list=('b1' 'b2' 'b3')
test=$(find_replace_in_list list "$find" replace_list)
echo "RESULT:${test[*]}"
RESULT: a b1 b2 b3 c d
'
```

Comment: `test` is not an array, it's a string.

Comment: You might have miss read it.   It's an array.

Comment: I don't see how. `test=$(command)` sets `test` to the output of `command`. The output is just a string.

Comment: You need to write `test=($(command))` to split it into an array.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something then, because my echo result matches the output of an array.

Comment: A string is treated as an array with just one element, so `${test[@]}` is the same as `${test}`. Try echoing `${test[1]}` and you'll see that it's not an array.

Comment: Corrected.  So I'm more clear for future: What is difference of ($()) vs $()?

Comment: Putting values inside `()` is how you create an array.

Comment: It's like the difference between `test=(1 2 3)` and `test="1 2 3"`

Comment: Last q:  If I echo back in the function new_array vs "${new_array[@]}", would the extra () be necessary to get a list result?

Comment: There's no way to get a list result.

Comment: The problem is that in bash, you aren't actually returning a value. `echo` converts everything to a string.

Comment: Arrays aren't really first-class values in `bash`, because all assignments are done by copying strings.

Comment: It gets worse. If any of the array elements have spaces in them, when you do `test=($(find_replace_in_list...))` those elements will be split into separate array elements. Adding quotes won't help, because quotes aren't processed after command substitution.

Comment: `bash` is not the appropriate language if you need complex structuring of data.

Comment: Seems I'm learning that the hard way.  Other than it's installed in most Linux distros by default, why use bash.  It seems rather limited.

Comment: It was designed for automating things that you would otherwise do by hand in the shell. And there are many simple applications that you can write pretty easily as well.

Comment: Avoid any method that "returns values" by command substitution. Return values by reference or through a temporary global variable.

Comment: fwiw, I ran the code and `typeset -p test` generates `declare -- test="a b1 b2 b3 c d"`, confirming that `test` is a string

Answer (score 1):

Return to another shared global variable:

```
find_replace_in_list() {
    local -n _list=$1 _replace_list=$3
    __A0=()

    for i in "${!_list[@]}"; do
        if [[ ${_list[i]} == "$2" ]]; then
            __A0+=("${_replace_list[@]}" "${_list[@]:i + 1}")
            break
        fi

        __A0[i]=${_list[i]}
    done
}
```

Modify original list:

```
find_replace_in_list() {
    local -n _list=$1 _replace_list=$3
    local counter=0

    for i in "${!_list[@]}"; do
        if [[ ${_list[i]} == "$2" ]]; then
            _list=("${_list[@]:0:counter}" "${_replace_list[@]}" "${_list[@]:i + 1}")
            break
        fi

        (( ++counter ))
    done
}
```

Comment: Your 2nd version, modifying the original list rather then creating another global var seems like it would be the cleanest version to me.  But I'm still pretty new to Bash.  Which would you use?

Comment: Is there any advantage to using 'break' vs simply 'return' if no other processing needs to be done outside the loop?

Comment: 1) I don't use any function like that (yet). It would depend on my purpose. 2) No there's no advantage. Use what you think is more efficient. 3) Please test by the way. If it doesn't work right it should be trivial to fix. Just tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nameref's` (`declare -n`) to pass data to/from the function.

Also, instead of trying to reindex a current array we'll just build a new array (`newlist` aka `_newlist`) on-the-fly thus allowing us to simplify the code.

Modifying the current code ...

```
find_replace_in_list(){
    # $1 = list (array)         : read from
    # $2 = find item (string)   
    # $3 = replace list (array) : read from
    # $4 = newlist (array)      : write to
    # $5 = number of times to match-n-replace (optional; default=1)

    local -n _list=$1
    local ptn=$2
    local -n _replace_list=$3
    local -n _newlist=$4
    local match_count=${5:-1}   # OP can add more logic to validate $5 is a positive integer

    _newlist=()

    for item in "${_list[@]}"
    do
        if [[ "${item}" = "${ptn}" && "${match_count}" -gt 0 ]]
        then
            _newlist+=( "${_replace_list[@]}" )
            (( match_count-- ))
        else
            _newlist+=( "${item}" )
        fi
    done
}
```

**Test #1** (one match & replacement):

```
list=('a' 'b' 'c' 'd')
find='b'
replace_list=('b1' 'b2' 'b3')
newlist=()
find_replace_in_list list "$find" replace_list newlist
typeset -p newlist
```

This generates:

```
declare -a newlist=([0]="a" [1]="b1" [2]="b2" [3]="b3" [4]="c" [5]="d")
```

**Test #2** (no matches found):

```
list=('a' 'b' 'c' 'd')
find='z'
replace_list=('z1' 'z2' 'z3')
newlist=()
find_replace_in_list list "$find" replace_list newlist
typeset -p newlist
```

This generates:

```
declare -a newlist=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d")
```

**Test #3a** (one match & replacement):

```
list=('a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'c')
find='c'
replace_list=('c7' 'c8' 'c9')
newlist=()
find_replace_in_list list "$find" replace_list newlist
typeset -p newlist
```

This generates:

```
declare -a newlist=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c7" [3]="c8" [4]="c9" [5]="d" [6]="c")
```

**Test #3b** (allow up to 999 match & replacements):

```
list=('a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'c')
find='c'
replace_list=('c7' 'c8' 'c9')
newlist=()
find_replace_in_list list "$find" replace_list newlist 999
typeset -p newlist
```

This generates:

```
declare -a newlist=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c7" [3]="c8" [4]="c9" [5]="d" [6]="c7" [7]="c8" [8]="c9")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the array as `stdout` and `readarray` the result but it forks a sub-shell:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Finds first item in array that matches find item, and replaces it with 1 or more array elements.
# Preserves sort order of original array.
find_replace_in_list() {
  # $1 = list
  # $2 = find item string
  # $3 = replace array.

  local -n _list=$1
  local -n _replace_list=$3

  for i in "${!_list[@]}"; do # Iterate over indices.

    if [ "${_list[$i]}" == "$2" ]; then
      # Insert the replace array starting at indice.
      local p=$((i + 1)) # Get indice just after match.
      local new_array=("${_list[@]:0:i}" "${_replace_list[@]}" "${_list[@]:p}")
      printf '%s\0' "${new_array[@]}"

      return # Break out of loop. Only replace first match.
    fi
  done
  # Nothing found.  Return orginal array.
  echo "${_list[@]}"
}

# shellcheck disable=SC2034 # nameref use
list=('a' 'b' 'c' 'd')
find='b'
# shellcheck disable=SC2034 # nameref use
replace_list=('b1' 'b2' 'b3')
readarray -td '' test < <(find_replace_in_list list "$find" replace_list)
printf 'RESULT: %s\n' "${test[*]}"
```

Or you can return the new array as reference:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Finds first item in array that matches find item, and replaces it with 1 or more array elements.
# Preserves sort order of original array.
find_replace_in_list() {
  # $1 = list nameref
  # $2 = find item string
  # $3 = replace array.nameref
  # ?$4 = optional new array nameref

  local -n _list=$1
  local -n _replace_list=$3
  if [ $# -eq 4 ]; then
    local -n _new_list=$4
  else
    local -a _new_list=()
  fi

  for i in "${!_list[@]}"; do # Iterate over indices.

    if [ "${_list[$i]}" == "$2" ]; then
      # Insert the replace array starting at indice.
      local p=$((i + 1)) # Get indice just after match.
      _new_list=("${_list[@]:0:i}" "${_replace_list[@]}" "${_list[@]:p}")
      
      # If no new array reference, print null delimited
      [ $# -lt 4 ] && printf '%s\0' "${_new_list[@]}"

      return # Break out of loop. Only replace first match.
    fi
  done
  # Nothing found.  Return orginal array.
  echo "${_list[@]}"
}

# shellcheck disable=SC2034 # nameref use
list=('a' 'b' 'c' 'd')
find='b'
# shellcheck disable=SC2034 # nameref use
replace_list=('b1' 'b2' 'b3')
find_replace_in_list list "$find" replace_list test
# shellcheck disable=SC2154 # nameref use
printf 'RESULT: %s\n' "${test[*]}"
```